# PHP extension: why int var changes to 0?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I am developing some PHP extension on C. I have few functions and several variables (char and int) defined globally at the top of C code. At php side I call the first function and pass some value for ssh_port argument - 22. this value set to global var. Then I call second function. But when I call third function - ssh_port variable suddenly gets 0 value ? Why ? The code is following:

```
#include <php.h>
#include "super_ssh.h"

#include <libssh2.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
#ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <sys/types.h>
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H
#include <sys/select.h>
#endif

#ifndef INADDR_NONE
#define INADDR_NONE (in_addr_t)-1
#endif

    char *ssh_ip, *ssh_username, *ssh_password, *remote_host, *last_error = "";
    size_t ssh_ip_len, ssh_username_len, ssh_password_len, remote_host_len;

    int ssh_port = 0, remote_port = 0, local_port = 0, to_close_tunnel = 0, thread_is_runnning = 0, is_authenticated = 0;

    PHP_FUNCTION(super_ssh_connect) {
      if (zend_parse_parameters(
        ZEND_NUM_ARGS(),
        "sl",
        &ssh_ip,
        &ssh_ip_len,
        &ssh_port
      ) == FAILURE) {
          return;
      }

      RETURN_LONG(ssh_port);

    }

    PHP_FUNCTION(super_ssh_authenticate) {
      if (zend_parse_parameters(
        ZEND_NUM_ARGS(),
        "ss",
        &ssh_username,
        &ssh_username_len,
        &ssh_password,
        &ssh_password_len
      ) == FAILURE) {
          return;
      }

      RETURN_LONG(ssh_port);
    }

    PHP_FUNCTION(super_ssh_open_tunnel) {

      if (zend_parse_parameters(
        ZEND_NUM_ARGS(),
        "sll",
        &remote_host,
        &remote_host_len,
        &remote_port,
        &local_port
      ) == FAILURE) {
          return;
      }

      RETURN_LONG(ssh_port);

    }





    ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX(arginfo_super_ssh_connect, 0, 0, 2)
      ZEND_ARG_INFO(0, ssh_ip)
      ZEND_ARG_INFO(0, ssh_port)
    ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

    ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX(arginfo_super_ssh_authenticate, 0, 0, 2)
        ZEND_ARG_INFO(0, ssh_username)
      ZEND_ARG_INFO(0, ssh_password)
    ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

    ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX(arginfo_super_ssh_open_tunnel, 0, 0, 3)
      ZEND_ARG_INFO(0, remote_host)
      ZEND_ARG_INFO(0, remote_port)
      ZEND_ARG_INFO(0, local_port)
    ZEND_END_ARG_INFO()

    zend_function_entry super_ssh_functions[] = {
      PHP_FE(super_ssh_connect, arginfo_super_ssh_connect)
      PHP_FE(super_ssh_authenticate, arginfo_super_ssh_authenticate)
      PHP_FE(super_ssh_open_tunnel, arginfo_super_ssh_open_tunnel)
      PHP_FE_END
    };

    zend_module_entry super_ssh_module_entry = {
      STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
      PHP_SUPER_SSH_EXTNAME,
      super_ssh_functions,
      NULL,
      PHP_MSHUTDOWN(super_ssh),
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      PHP_SUPER_SSH_VERSION,
      STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES,
    };

    ZEND_GET_MODULE(super_ssh);
```

And the code of PHP side:

```
<?php

var_dump(super_ssh_connect("234.43.23.3", 22));
var_dump(super_ssh_authenticate("dfds", "mofsdfdsnitor"));
var_dump(super_ssh_open_tunnel("server", 993, 4444));
```

Actual result is:

int(22) int(22) int(0)

Expected result is:

int(22) int(22) int(22)

So the question is why the ssh_port variable gets 0 value ? I don't set it anywhere! Really can't understand it :(

The interesting thing is that the problem is actual for apache php. So it happens when I run the script from browser. (apache2 + php)

If I try the same compilation for PHP CLI it works as expected, the output is:

int(22) int(22) int(22)

May be it is somehow touching with garbage collector ? Or maybe you just can me suggest better way for my code how to work with variables?

My environment:

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, apache2 + PHP Version 7.2.17-1, and PHP CLI is PHP 7.2.2 (cli) (built: Apr 29 2019 09:57:40) ( ZTS DEBUG )

I noticed problematic code, if I comment the following code frpm third super_ssh_open_tunnel function - it works.

Commenting this code make it work, without this code I still have 22 in the ssh_port var

```
 if (zend_parse_parameters(
        ZEND_NUM_ARGS(),
        "sll",
        &remote_host,
        &remote_host_len,
        &remote_port,
        &local_port
      ) == FAILURE) {
          return;
      }
```

Comment: I don't know anything about C but does this line just set default values?  int ssh_port = 0, remote_port = 0, local_port = 0, to_close_tunnel = 0, thread_is_runnning = 0, is_authenticated = 0;

Comment: I am also not expert in C. This is why I am asking here. As I guess yes - it should define variable with int type and set 0 value

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you have is an undefined behavior.

Firstly `PHP_FUNCTION` is expanded to `void zif_FUNCNAME(zend_execute_data *execute_data, zval *return_value)`.

According to [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> **6.8.6.4 The return statement**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1. A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is void. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.
>
> **6.9.1 Function definitions**
>
> 12. If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

So, in your case `zend_parse_parameters` returns `FAILURE` which is then translated into "ending before reaching closing `{`, so that's why the value of `ssh_port` is never returned.

The reason why `zend_parse_parameters` fails is because one of the arguments is not initialized different than 0

Comment: Thank u for your answer, but I just checked, zend_parse_parameters - doesn't fail

Comment: I just saw your edit. If you commented the code and correct value for `ssh_port` is displayed doesn't this mean that the `if` clause commented made the function to return early by calling `return;` and the `var_dump` to display what `return;` gives which happen to be a 0?

Comment: You know, not a fact. I am sure that zend_parse_parameters is success and it doesn't go into if(zend_parse_parameters) block. I think really it set 0 to ssh_port variable for some reason

Comment: Also I noticed that remote_port also has 0 value. But local_port gets right value